# restler returning all escaped doublequote chars?

Tags: php, restler

K, so I have something like this.  I'm trying to figure out how to *not* escape the double quotes.  I think this is restler doing it...but I haven't been able to find docs or hints in the restler code about what I need to change.  If I do a str_replace('"', '*', jason_encode...), it displays fine with the stars...so it is not json_encode messing it up...:

```
....
$thisDeal = new deals_search_element();
$thisDeal->deal_name="name2";
$thisDeal->venue_address="address2";
$thisDeal->latlong=$latlong;

$myDeals[] = $thisDeal;
return json_encode( array( "deals_search"=>$myDeals ));
```

My output is this:

```
"{\"deals_search\":[{\"deal_name\":\"test name 1\",\"deal_venue\":\"\",\"venue_address\":\"test address 1\",\"venue_city\":\"\",\"venue_state\":\"\",\"latlong\":\"1...
```

I know the data doesn't match the code...but just trust me on all that and the point is...the double quotes are escaped.  How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  I was trying to encode myself where restler handles it automatically.  I was being thick about that part.  lol

So line:

```
return json_encode( array( "deals_search"=>$myDeals ));
```

...had to become just...

```
return array( "deals_search"=>$myDeals );
```